# Regex to match only part of certain line

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have some config file from which I need to extract only some values. For example, I have this:

```
PART
{
    title = Some Title
    description = Some description here.    // this 2 params are needed 
    tags = qwe rty    // don't need this param
    ...
}
```

I need to extract value of certain param, for example `description`'s value. How do I do this in Python3 with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex, assuming that the file text is in `txt`:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'^\s*description\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=(//)|$)', txt, re.M)
print(m.group(1))
```

Let me explain.
`^` matches at beginning of line.
Then `\s*` means zero or more spaces (or tabs)
`description` is your anchor for finding the value part.
After that we expect `=` sign with optional spaces before or after by denoting `\s*=\s*`.
Then we capture everything after the `=` and optional spaces, by denoting `(.*?)`. This expression is captured by parenthesis. Inside the parenthesis we say match anything (the dot) as many times as you can find (the asterisk) in a non greedy manner (the question mark), that is, stop as soon as the following expression is matched.

The following expression is a lookahead expression, starting with `(?=` which matches the thing right after the `(?=`.
And that thing is actually two options, separated by the vertical bar `|`.

The first option, to the left of the bar says `//` (in parenthesis to make it atomic unit for the vertical bar choice operation), that is, the start of the comment, which, I suppose, you don't want to capture.
The second option is `$`, meaning the end of the line, which will be reached if there is no comment `//` on the line.
So we look for everything we can after the first `=` sign, until either we meet a `//` pattern, or we meet the end of the line. This is the essence of the `(?=(//)|$)` part.

We also need the `re.M` flag, to tell the regex engine that we want `^` and `$` match the start and end of lines, respectively. Without the flag they match the start and end of the entire string, which isn't what we want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach would be to use an established configuration file system. Python has built-in support for INI-like files in the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) module.

However, if you just *desperately* need to get the string of text in that file after the `description`, you could do this:

```
def get_value_for_key(key, file):
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.lstrip()
        if line.startswith(key + " ="):
            return line.split("=", 1)[1].lstrip()
```

You can use it with a call like: `get_value_for_key("description", "myfile.txt")`. The method will return `None` if nothing is found. It is assumed that your file will be formatted where there is a space and the equals sign after the key name, e.g. `key = value`.

This avoids regular expressions altogether and preserves any whitespace on the right side of the value. (If that's not important to you, you can use `strip` instead of `lstrip`.)

Why avoid regular expressions? They're expensive and really not ideal for this scenario. Use simple string matching. This avoids importing a module and simplifies your code. But really I'd say to convert to a supported configuration file format.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty simple regex, you just need a positive lookbehind, and optionally something to remove the comments. (do this by appending `?(//)?` to the regex)

```
r"(?<=description = ).*"
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL4dQ9/1)

Comment: comments was added by me just for claryfying :P

Comment: This will match the doc line too.

Comment: What is the "doc line"?

Comment: The line after `//`.